# Issue with refetching specific GraphQL obvervable query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm very new to React and GraphQL(Apollo) and learning the stack.

I have a React Component that loads some page data and there is a "Reload" button on the page.

**Problem:**

> - I want to refetch the data when I click on "Reload" button.
> - However, I could not find a way to refetch the data from queryObservable.
> - **How do I refetch the data from QueryObservable? Is there anyway to call refetch?**

I tried using `reFetchObservableQueries()` however, this reloads the page and refetches everything. Can I specifically refetch only a single observable?

This is my code:

```
getPageQueryObservable = (contentId, key, paginated = false) => {
    const query = contentId ? TreeQuery : RootLevelQuery;
    const defaultVariables = 'Test';
    const variablesForPagination = {
      paginationLimit: INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE,
      ...defaultVariables
    };

    return this.props.apolloClient.watchQuery({
      query,
      variables: paginated === true ? variablesForPagination : defaultVariables
    });
  };

  loadPages = async (paginated = false) => {
    const { pages: localPages } = this.state;
    const { id, key } = this.props;

    const queryObservable = this.getPageQueryObservable(
      id,
      key,
      paginated
    );


    // I want to ideally call this stuff again..When "Reload" button is clicked.
    this.querySubscription = queryObservable.subscribe({
      next: ({ data, loading }) => {
      ....
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `query` with the same query and variables but a `fetchPolicy` of `network-only` in order to refetch the query. This should update the cache and therefore any relevant Observables.

```
await client.query({ query, variables, fetchPolicy: 'network-only' })
```

However, there's really no reason to use `watchQuery` directly. Instead, you should use the hook API to fetch and refetch your data.

```
const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(query, { variables })
```

Not only does this reduce boilerplate, but now refetching is as simple as

```
await refetch()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have however used `queryObservable.refetch()` to solve my problem instead of querying again. That got the data again and re-rendered the DOM.